# Any feedback on Google's "Temporal Fusion Transformers for Multi-horizon Time Series Forecasting" Model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I am trying to build a time series model to help forecast the demand of semiconductor chip-level products of a semiconductor company.  They have roughly 50 products and several variations of each product.  Wondering if you have any feedback on Google's "[Temporal Fusion Transformers for Multi-horizon Time Series Forecasting](https://aihub.cloud.google.com/u/0/p/products%2F9f39ad8d-ad81-4fd9-8238-5186d36db2ec)" model?  Additionally let me know if you can recommend another model.

Comment: This question is rather nonspecific and overly broad, and that kind of question isn't best for this website (see: the [help]). Is there a specific question you have about this model, or a particular concern that you have in your use case?